# Accidentally change sudo user to /bin/false

Tags: sudo, su

### More Update

In short, I have to execute a command (sudo nano /etc/passwd) using a Sudoer Account which I know the username and password but I have to login as a non-Sudoer Account

### trial #1 su - $USER -s /bin/sh Not Working! since the Sudoer Account doesn't have a shell account (accidentally set to /bin/false)

I have Ubuntu machine with only 2 users:
1. Admin (sudoer)
2. Mysql (non-sudoer)

accidentally changed the admin user on /etc/passwd into /bin/false

now I cannot login as admin, but still can login as mysql as generic user, non-sudo

How could I change back the /etc/passwd?

Is there any way doing this?

### Updated

I've tried su - $USER -s /bin/sh while login as user POSTGRES but it's not working, since I cannot get into the shell because of /bin/false applied on ADMIN

so sudo is the last hope.. I think..

is anyone know how to execute sudo on ADMIN while we're login as non-sudo user?
ex.. login as USER_POSTGRES, and execute a sudo COMMAND as Admin?

Comment: Actually there is a 3rd user `root`... Answered by http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 2):

This makes little sense - you probably have a "root" user as well - although it may not be possible to log in as root.

You can recover your system by rebooting it - and either changing/adding the boot "lernel" line to include "init=/bin/bash" which will give you a root login so you can edit your password file, or by using a recovery disk to do something similar.   (See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword))

Comment: Physical altering is not possible at the moment, I am still out of town. I've tried su - user -s /bin/sh with no success, it said "no directory, logging in with HOME=/"... I know my sudo password, is there any way to execute that without su to the user?

Comment: Its probably not possible to do what you are trying to to - effectively you are in the position of trying to hack your own server !   There is a command "sudo" which allows you to run a program as another user, but you need to have this set up to allow it - and I'd be extremely surprised if the mysql user is allowed to do this.

Comment: If you reisssue the command su - admin -s /bin/sh   and then run /usr/bin/whoami  what is the result ?   If that reports "admin" then you should be able to do whatever you need to do (ie su to root and modify /etc/passwd) - you may just need to specify full paths to the commands you use.

Comment: yes, I'm feeling silly hacking my own server.. I've tried those commands, and return "no directory, logging in with HOME=/"  So basically I cannot get into my own account regardless I have the password

Comment: Not neccessarily so - it could simply be that your path is incorrect and you are being logged in without a home directory, but, critically - being logged in as admin user which then gives you admin users permissions.  Try issue the command again, then go cd /home/admin; ls  and see if your files are there.

Comment: It's weird, /home/admin folder is gone, and home folder is under ROOT ownership which I cannot add folder there. I guess that's why "su" is not working since the directory is non-existence. Any way-around for this situation?